# Umbraco child elements not registering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have a page running fine locally but throwing an error when running on the server:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

The line in throwing the error is:

```
var selection = CurrentPage.Site().FirstChild("Members").FirstChild("General").FirstChild("Visits").Children("VisitsListing").Where("Visible");
```

Changing it to this runs OK so it seems to be the last call to `.Children` that throws it:

```
var selection = CurrentPage.Site().FirstChild("Members").FirstChild("General").FirstChild("Visits");
```

I've checked the document types and structure and they seem to be the same locally and on the server.

Under `Content` there is an entry for `Visits` with a list of entries below it, all with document type `Visits Listing`.

Anyone any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried to republish the entire site?

Comment: I haven't. Never occurred to me to try that.

Comment: @Eyescream: That actually worked! Thank you! Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. =)

Comment: great! glad it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should republish the entire site to update the umbraco.config cache file